# Xamarin.Forms Sqlite-net NotSupportedException on ManyToOne relationship "Don't know about <model>"

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using sqlite net extensions library in my xamarin.forms application. I code in my PCL the database code and models.

When I call SQLiteConnection.CreateTable() I get an error
`System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Cigars.Models.Cigar`

Smoke is a child of Cigar, it has a ManyToOne relationship.
Here are the models:

Smoke

```
public class Smoke
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int SmokeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Cigar))]
    public int CigarId { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    //why is this not recognized?
    [ManyToOne]
    public Cigar Cigar { get; set; }

}
```

Cigar

```
public class Cigar
{

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int CigarId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Length { get; set; }
}
```

My database call that causes the exception to be thrown:

```
private SQLiteConnection db;

public Database(string path)
{
    db = new SQLiteConnection(path);
    db.CreateTable<Cigar>();
    db.CreateTable<Smoke>(); //this throws the error
}
```

Comment: You are only passing one parameter to the SQLiteConnection constructor thus I would have to assume you are using *not* using `Sqlite.Net.SQLiteConnection` which requires a `ISQLitePlatform` object as the first parameter and thus `SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes.ManyToOneAttribute` would not be known to that type of `SQLiteConnection`.

Comment: @SushiHangover I was not aware of two types of the same name SQLiteConnection. This code is in my PCL, so will I have to implement something to obtain an instance of each platforms ISQLitePlatform? Also do you know what the classes that implement ISQLitePlatform  are called?

Comment: There are three flavors of the SQLite extensions provide, not sure which one you are using, I would follow the links depending upon which flavor you are using and look at the integration tests... https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/ffa73e87ab948c1dd3d584572bcbdab19d65a17a?at=master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had installed two different libraries for sqlite, both containing a `SQLiteConnection`.

I needed to use the `Sqlite.Net.SQLiteConnection` class for sqlite net extensions. Not the `Sqlite.SQLiteConnection` I was using.

As SushiHangover pointed out, this `Sqlite.Net.SQLiteConnection` takes a first argument of type `ISQLitePlatform`.

To obtain a reference for this, I defined an interface that provides the signature of a method to return a `ISQLitePlatform`:

```
public interface ISQLitePlatformInstance
{
    ISQLitePlatform GetSQLitePlatformInstance();
}
```

And I implemented the interface in my Droid project ( the platform I'm building against):

```
public class SQLitePlatformInstance : ISQLitePlatformInstance
{

    public ISQLitePlatform GetSQLitePlatformInstance()
    {
        return new SQLitePlatformAndroid();
    }

}
```